# Why is this a homogenous equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Why is $N(x, y)$ coefficient of a homogenous equation?

Comment: A function $f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$ if $f(tx) = t^nf(x)$.

Comment: Where in general $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\lambda x=(\lambda x_1,\dots,\lambda x_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, a (polynomial) function $f$ is homogenous of degree $d$ if when written as a sum of monomials, each monomial has the same total degree (which is $d$).

So, when we write $N(x,y) = x^2-xy$, we see the first term $x^2$ is of degree two, and the second term $-xy$ is of degree two, so it seems like it should be of degree two.

Checking the definition, we get that:
$$N(tx,ty) = (tx)^2-(tx)(ty) = t^2x^2-t^2xy = t^2(x^2-xy) = t^2N(x,y)$$
It follows that $N(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $2$.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, both $M$ and $N$ are homogeneous (of degree 2.)  But in the context of 1st order DE's, we usually introduce "homogeneous" differently.  If we rearrange your equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-xy}$$

then we see that dividing the top and bottom by $x^2$ gives

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1+(y/x)^2}{1-(y/x)}$$

So now the substitution $v=y/x$ will change this equation into a separable one.